# How to install Phusion Passenger using RVM on Rackspace server?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, phusion-passenger, ruby, rackspace

I am getting ready to start hosting my own Ruby applications. I already have RVM installed on my production server. Now I would like to install Passenger.

I have Ruby 1.9.2 set as the default. I installed the passenger gem and ran `passenger-install-apache2-module`. This displayed a list of missing dependencies, one of which being OpenSSL support for Ruby. It explained that I needed to re-install Ruby with OpenSSL support. I don't know how to do this and don't know why it is not there to begin with. Here is the list of other errors:

- GNU C++ compiler... not found
- Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
- OpenSSL development headers... not found
- Zlib development headers... not found
- Ruby development headers... found
- OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
- RubyGems... found
- Rake... found at /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/rake
- rack... found
- Apache 2... found at /usr/sbin/httpd
- Apache 2 development headers... not found
- Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... not found
- Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... not found

It seems like many of these things should have already been available. Did I install RVM wrong? Is there an easier way to get Passenger up and running without installing a bunch of dependencies that I may never use later? What should I do?

**Update:** I forgot to mention this is a RedHat server hosted at Rackspace. I'm not sure if there is a Rackspace recommended way of doing this. I know they maintain their own list of trusted packages/repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rackspace wasn't much help, but this ended up being easier than I thought and there were no issues. I simply followed the directions that passenger gave me. It said I needed to install a bunch of packages, so I ran through each one, one at a time (i.e. `sudo yum install openssl-devel`). None of the packages conflicted with other packages I had installed because they were all new (I didn't need to update any). Then I ran the passenger installer again and it was able to compile itself just fine.

The only gotcha that I came across is that Passenger will only let you run one version of Ruby, so when you install Passenger through RVM, make sure you are `rvm use`-ing the version of Ruby you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Passenger (specifically mod_passenger) and here's how I did it.  My environment is CentOS 6, x86_64.

1. Install required rpms

   ```
   yum install httpd httpd-devel openssl-devel mod_ssl
   ```
2. Add EPEL repo.  Remember to edit /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo and disable it by setting  enabled to 0. Actual source for epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm will not be from fedoraproject.org/... as you will actually be hitting a mirror server.

   ```
   wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
   rpm -ivh epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
   ```
3. Set up to use yum repo at stealthymonkeys.com which hosts rpms for passenger.  Installs mod_passenger which requires epel repo for some dependent rpms.

   ```
   rpm -Uvh http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/6/passenger-release.noarch.rpm
   ```
4. Install mod_passenger using the following command.

   ```
   yum   --enablerepo=epel  --enablerepo=passenger  install mod_passenger
   ```

Not able to provide better answer as I don't know your environment but hopefully this will help.